# C++ preprocessor path root

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, filepath

Is it possible to process a file path using the C++ preprocessor?

What I want is this
`GETROOT( __FILE__ )`
expanding into 
`\\myserver\myshare\`

Supposing that the path to the file is something like `\\myserver\myshare\folder\folder\file.txt`

I'm using `mcpp` on Windows XP

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591873/how-do-i-write-a-cpp-dir-macro-similar-to-file I Personally would use the makefile approach, but that would depend on your build system

Comment: @David Ashmore I can see why you say that, but the question is in a different environment and in both cases, there was no spot-on solution.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the compiler, the preprocessor behaves slightly different on GCC/Microsoft etc.
There is not standard-conform way to do that..

On Windows you might try to use build environment variables. Visual Studio can expose these values ($(SolutionDir) etc) to the preprocessor context. Just add a preprocessor value like ROOT_PATH="$(SolutionDir)" (C/C++ -> preprocessor in project settings).

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not, at least not in a standard way.  I couldn't say for sure that there are no compilers anywhere in the world that do it, but it seems unlikely.

What's the use-case that means you can't do it at runtime?

Comment: I'm using the preprocessor to massage files for a DSL, so the output is not C++.