# __FILE__ not giving full path

Tags: c

If I do this below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

 printf ("%s\n",__FILE__);
 return 0;

}

>gcc cfilename.c
>./a.out
>cfilename.c
>pwd
>/home/tek/cpp
> gcc -v
> gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
```

only file name is printed, I think it should print it with complete path, google search tells me people asking help to get only file name?

Comment: `__FILE__` just passes out whatever it was you passed in to gcc; so you may want to do this: `gcc $(pwd)/filename.c`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591873/how-do-i-write-a-cpp-dir-macro-similar-to-file

Answer (score 4):

The ISO C standard (currently C11) has this to say about the content of the `__FILE__` predefined macro:

> `__FILE__`: The presumed name of the current source file (a character string literal).

And that's about it. There is no mandate on the format of the content so I suspect a implementation could probably get away with setting it to `"some file I found in the /src tree"` and still claim conformance.

So it's basically up to the implementation as to what it puts in there. You'll need to investigate specific implementations to see how they handle it. The `gcc` compiler, for example, uses the file exactly as you specified on the command line so, if you want the full path, it's the command line you'll have to change, something like:

```
gcc -o myexec $(pwd)/myexec.c
```

It's interesting to note that `gcc` seems to do the *opposite* for included files. When you use:

```
#include "myheader.h"
```

the `__FILE__` macro is set to the full expansion of the header file.

---

If you have an implementation that *doesn't* set `__FILE__` in the manner you need, there's nothing stopping you from creating your *own* with something like:

```
dodgycc -o myexec -DMY_FILE_NAME=$(pwd)/myexec.c myexec.c
```

(where the `-D` option of the `dodgycc` compiler defines a preprocessor token to be what you need).

Comment: Source files are always found at the given path, relative to the CWD, no ambiguity. A header with a given name, or include-name token with multiple components, is found relative to any of the configured header search paths. If `__FILE__` didn't mention the search path the header was found at, then multiple files could provide the same value for `__FILE__`, which would be ambiguous.

Comment: … Also it bears mentioning that if you want `__FILE__` to produce a particular result, the `#line` directive is the way to go. Anyway, +1.

Comment: Since v.8 `gcc` has options `-fmacro-prefix-map`,  `-ffile-prefix-map` to modify how `__FILE__` expands. See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487986/file-macro-shows-full-path